# exchange Eth to Fund(real cash), then..?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, myetherwallet, ethereum-classic

I'm just learning Ethereum, and I have two questions.

1. Is the total number of ethers capped in the main Network? I mean, there are 10,000,000 ethers, for example, in the network, and all currencies are rotating with transactions. Am I right...?
2. If I exchanged 5 ethers to the cash(fund), where the ethers has gone,,? who got the ethers that I exchanged..?

I am not sure I understand exactly the concept of Ethereum,, but I am just curious..

Answer (score 1):

1. First off no there is no hardcap but a hardcap of 120 million has been discussed. There are 99m in circulation not 10 million as you stated.
2. Secondly, if you "exchange Ethereum to funds" you sell your Ethereum to someone else who is buying it.